# How to secure a communication between Android App and Tomcat server?

Tags: android, security, https, tomcat7

I'm trying to `secure` the communication between a `Tomcat server and an android app`!

I opted for a `simple https configuration` and followed this tutorial : http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/ on how to configure Tomcat To Support SSL Or Https.
The key was succesfully generated, and https is accessible. When I tested my android app with it, it did not recognize the server.

After a bit of research, I understood that android only works with BKS keys, and that some code is needed to complete the security according to : [How to create a BKS (BouncyCastle) format Java Keystore that contains a client certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065379/how-to-create-a-bks-bouncycastle-format-java-keystore-that-contains-a-client-c) and [Few questions about SSL on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888298/few-questions-about-ssl-on-android),  but I still do'nt undestand what exacty are the steps to follow!!

Can anybody help me understand this please!! Cheers!

Comment: who issued your certificate ?

Comment: nobody :S I used the keytool to generate one ... but no authority is included

Comment: that's why. android won't allow you to use a self signed certificate for https connections unless install it on the device.

Comment: What do you mean by "it". And how can I install it ??

Comment: the self signed certificate. I don't know how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using a self-signed certificate.

There are two ways you can do this. :

1. Include the BKS certificate in your application's raw resources and provide this KeyStore as an object to the TrustManagerFactory.
2. You can tell the SSLSocketFactory to ignore the certificate and accept all certificates over SSL without verifying them.

The exact implementation really depends on your implementation of network connection (HTTPClient vs HttpsURLConnection) and your needs. You can find the relevant implementations elsewhere on stackoverflow.

Comment: I would add a warning that you should never accept all SSL certificates. This leaves your program vulnerable to [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).